# Where is the PlugInArea.WorkRoom in EPiServer CMS 6

Tags: episerver, episerver-6

I've created a `GuiPlugIn` in EPiServer CMS 6 and as I was doing it, I noticed that the `PlugInArea` enum has a `WorkRoom` value.

If I set my `GuiPlugIn` to target `PlugInArea.WorkRoom`, where in the CMS will it be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workroom was a part of the demo template set for EPiServer CMS 5. It still is. But now the templates are renamed to be called "AlloyTech". Download the demo templates from world.episerver.com and find the workrooms in edit-mode under "customer zone".